# Adding bootstrap mvc / mysql connector packages in NuGet manager

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I'm using VS 2017 Community Edition and I'm having a hard time locating packages I used to use. Package Manager cant find Mysql connector, or bootstrap mvc. I wonder if this is because it only goes to VS Marketplace? How do I get it to search these things?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Do you mean you could no longer find the nuget package `MySqlConnector` and `bootstrap` via NuGet Packager Manager (Tools->NuGet Packager Manager->Manage NuGet Packages for solution->Browse)? What is the result when you search those two package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Project tag on the top

**-->** Manage NuGet Packages

**-->** Browse <-the thing you want->

Comment: That was it - I was going to extensions and updates by mistake.